# Simultaneous Deploys from Github with Cloud Build for Multi-tenant architecture

Tags: google-cloud-platform, devops, multi-tenant, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

My company is developing a web application and have decided that a multi-tenant architecture would be most appropriate for isolating individual client installs. An install would represent an organization (a nonprofit, for example) and not an individual users account. Each install would be several Cloud Run applications bucketed to an individual GCP project.

We want to be able to take advantage of Cloud Build's GitHub support to deploy from our `main` branch in GitHub to each individual client install. So far, I've been able to get this setup working across two individual GCP projects, where Cloud Build runs in each project individually and deploys to the individual GCP project Cloud Runs at roughly the same time and with the same duration. (Cloud Build does some processing unique to each client install so the build processes in each install are not performing redundant work)

My specific question is can we scale this deployment technique up? Is there any constraint preventing using Cloud Build in multiple GCP projects to deploy to our client installs, or will we hit issues when we continue to add more GCP projects? I know that so far this technique works for 2 installs, but will it work for 20, 200 installs?

Answer (score 2):

You are limited to 10 concurrent builds per project. But if you run one cloud build per project, there is no limitation or known issues.